# Adjust Refresh Rate

Tags: display

I'm curious as to what the suggested method for adjusting screen refresh rate is. There doesn't seem to be an option under the display settings, despite being a fairly standard and important setting. It's unfortunate being locked at 60Hz on a 144Hz monitor. Any suggestions?

Comment: RIP Elementary OS. It was fun while it was functional.

Comment: A solution from the Ubuntu forum: 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/147580/how-to-see-change-screen-refresh-rate-or-monitor-frequency#155351

Comment: You sexy beast. That does the trick well enough. If you reply as an answer I can mark as solved. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution from the Ubuntu forum:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/147580/how-to-see-change-screen-refresh-rate-or-monitor-frequency#155351

Answer (score 0):

In the latest Elementary OS I had to use the verbose version of the xrandr command, including the output device, for this to work:

`xrandr --output eDP-1 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 59.93`

If I use the shorter version as explained in the (old) Ubuntu thread, eg. `xrandr -r 59.93`,  nothing happens.

Check the output device (mine is eDP-1) from the 2nd line of `xrandr` output.  Add this as a startup application to have it set on every login. In System Settings -> Applications -> Tab Startup you can add a custom command.

Would be nice though if there was a way without adjusting xorg.conf or adding a startup script to make this permanent, since also during boot the screen flickers.  Somehow on my recent HP Probook 60.01Hz is the default rate and makes my eyes bleed (screen flickers in the dark areas), whilst using 59.93 (2nd available mode listed by xrandr) doesn't.  weird..